# UIViewAnimation setAnimationDidStopSelector Undeclared Selector, Will It Crash?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation

i would like to know what happens when you assign a selector to animationDidStopSelector that is not declared.

For example:

```
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(doThis)];
```

i have this line of code. after calling the animation, it should call method, doThis, right? But if I didn't declare doThis or let's say I forgot to declare doThis, will my app crash?
Or will UIView just ignore it? thanks.

Comment: It will crash, because it wil look for the selector to be called when animation is stopped, by the way why would you define it, when you don't need it?

Comment: oh. i'm just curious. because there are times when you think you already declared the method but you forgot. or when you declared it before but deleted it because you don't need it anymore and you forgot that you are calling it as a selector. anyway, thank you for replying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will crash *if* the animation has a delegate (`setAnimationDelegate:`) and *if* that delegate does not implement `doThis`.

But it will not crash if the animation has no delegate, because there will be no one to send the message to. Nothing will happen.

Also, all of the above assumes you are using old-fashioned animation "blocks", constructing the animation with `[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil]` and ending them with `[UIView commitAnimations]`. If you use the modern form of animation construction with `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` and its friends, there is no delegate and no `didStopSelector`; your calls in that regard will be ignored, because the `completion:` handler fulfills that role.